# Using PLY with python -OO?

Tags: python, ply

I have a system where an application is started with:

```
python -OO my_app.py
```

I cannot change the way the application is started but I have full control of the application. When adding a parser to the application using [PLY](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/) I was bitten by the fact that -OO removes the docstrings that PLY relies on.

Is it impossible to use PLY in an application which is started with -OO? Are there any clever Python tricks that can be used to solve this problem?

I have been thinking on using Cython to compile the parser module. I am not sure that it can be done, and it would add a layer of complexity, so before I go down that road I would appreciate any other ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, classic case of finding the answer just as the question was written...

It is clearly stated in the PLY manual that there is an [optimize mode](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply.html#ply_nn38) which is used for this exact use case. I thought it referred to another kind of performance optimization.

Note that since -OO removes docstrings, instantiating your lexer and parser with optimize=1 will not handle empty rules like the one below:

```
def p_commands(self, p):
    """commands :
                | commands command"""
    # This will fail when running optimized

def p_command(self, p):
    """command : foo
               | bar"""
    p[0] = p[1]
```